# Accessing members of a class within a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

```
class item
{
private:
    std::string name;
    double price;
    int quantity;

public:
    void item();
    void setName(string itemName);
    std::string getName();
    void setPrice(double itemPrice);
    double getPrice();
    void setQuantity(int itemQuantity);
    int getQuantity();
};

class list
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<item>> notepad;

public:
    bool isEmpty();
    void addList();
    void printLists(bool printTotalPrice);
    void addItem();
    void removeItem();
    void editItem();
    void importList(ifstream& iFile);
    void exportList(ofstream& oFile);
};
```

Here is where I am having trouble.  For my function list::addItem() I want the user to enter a string in order to search the notepad vector's first row elements ONLY in order to find a match.

Something like this...

```
          for (int i = 0; i < notepad.size(); ++i)
             if (user's entered string) == first element of 'i'th vector.getName()
```

... match found

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( user_entered_string == notepad[i][0].getName() )
```

`[i]` gets the 'i'th vector from `notepad`.

`[0]` gets the first `item` from that result.

`.getName()` is called on that result.